# Передать переменную в $.ajax

Tags: javascript

При нажатии кнопки и подтверждении выполняется Ajax запрос.

```
function Validator(id_){
   if(confirm("Вы подтверждаете операцию?") ){
     var ttt= document.getElementById(id_);
     alert(ttt.id);
      $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '2.php',
                data:{'1btn':'1'},
                success: function(data) {
                    $("p").html(data);
                }
            });
      return(true);

   }else{
     alert("Операция отменена!");
      return(false);

   }
}
<p></p>
<button id="1btn" class="b1" value="open" onclick="JavaScript:return Validator(this.id);">Start</button>
<button id="50btn" class="b1" value="open" onclick="JavaScript:return Validator(this.id);">Stop</button> 
<button id="51btn" class="b2" value="open" onclick="JavaScript:return Validator(this.id);">Test</button>
```

Как в data:`{'1btn':'1'}` передать значение переменной ttt.id ?

Comment: `data:{1btn:'1', id: ttt},` потом в пхп файле получаете значение переменной через `$_GET("id")`

Comment: на сколько помню передать можно только в самом запросе, например 2.php?id= + ttt.id , а затем прочитать success (я точно не помню какой объект там содержит переменную с текстом запроса)

Answer (score 2):

Зачем создавать лишние переменные, если у вас уже входной параметр в функции и есть id?
просто заменить

`data:{1btn:'1'}`

на

`data:{'id':id_}`

и при отправке в консоли браузера (в разделе "Network") проконтролируйте, какие данные он отсылает.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так. работает.

```
function Validator(id_){
   if(confirm("Вы подтверждаете операцию?") ){
     var ttt= document.getElementById(id_);
     //alert(ttt.id);
      $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'runner.php?' + ttt.id + '=1',
                success: function(data) {
                    $("p").html(data);
                }
            });
      //return(true);

   }else{
     alert("Операция отменена!");
      //return(false);

   }
}
```